# Is there a way in JIRA REST APIs to create/get API Tokens?

Tags: rest, authentication, postman, token, jira

In Jira, if you want to consume its REST API, you need to authenticate. This can be done with *Basic Auth* by giving a **API Token** in place of password, as mentionned here :

- https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

To create and get an API Token, you have to do it *manually*, here :

- https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens

Well, my question is quite simple :

**Is there a way (it means an endpoint in Jira REST API) to serve this need ?**

**Is there some endpoints to create and get an API Tokens (e.g: launched in Postman) ?**

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Typically not because to access such an API you'd need an API token. Accessing such an API with username/password defeats some of the principles behind API/access tokens.

Comment: Gosh !... You are right, Hans. 
My bad. Sorry for inconvenience.
Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint would still be useful to create a new token (using an existing token) and then revoke the current one. This is a requirement from my company and I'd like to automate it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).